# Android: Why doesn't this Transformation.map run when trying to assign to a variable?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-livedata

I am trying to use the Firebase API in my project but `Transformations.map` for the variable `authenticationState` in the View Model does not run. I have been following Google's tutorial [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-login/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/firebaseui_login_sample/LoginViewModel.kt) (link goes to the ViewModel of that project).

I want to be able to add the `Transformations.map` code to the `FirebaseUserLiveData` file later but I cant seem to figure out why it doesn't run.

**FirebaseUserLiveData**

```
class FirebaseUserLiveData: LiveData<FirebaseUser?>() {

    private val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
        value = firebaseAuth.currentUser
    }


    override fun onActive() {
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener { authStateListener }
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}
```

**SearchMovieFragmentViewModel**

```
class SearchMovieFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {

    enum class AuthenticationState {
        AUTHENTICATED, UNAUTHENTICATED, INVALID_AUTHENTICATION
    }

    var authenticationState = Transformations.map(FirebaseUserLiveData()) { user ->
        Log.d("TEST", "in the state function")
        if (user != null) {
            AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED
        } else {
            AuthenticationState.UNAUTHENTICATED
        }
    }
```

**SearchMovieFragment**

```
class SearchMovieFragment : Fragment(), MovieSearchItemViewModel {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = SearchMovieFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var searchMovieFragmentViewModel: SearchMovieFragmentViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: SearchMovieFragmentBinding
    private lateinit var movieRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.search_movie_fragment, container, false)
        searchMovieFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchMovieFragmentViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewmodel = searchMovieFragmentViewModel

        binding.signOutButton.setOnClickListener {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(requireContext())
        }

        searchMovieFragmentViewModel.authenticationState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { state ->
            when (state) {
                AUTHENTICATED -> searchMovieFragmentViewModel.signedIn = View.VISIBLE
                UNAUTHENTICATED -> searchMovieFragmentViewModel.signedIn = View.GONE
            }
        })
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: because FirebaseUserLiveData() is not emitting any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)` instead of `{ authStateListener }`

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not keeping the reference of `FirebaseUserLiveData()` once you start observing it like `Transformations.map(FirebaseUserLiveData()) { user ->`.
You have to have the reference of the **Livedata** you are mapping or transferring to another form of **Livedata**.

It is like a **chain of observation**, All LiveData in the **chain** should be observed or should have some kind of observer down the line, The main use-case is to transform some form of livedata to something you want, For Example:

```
class YourRepository{  // your repo, that connected to a network that keeps up to date some data
  val IntegerResource: LiveData<Int> = SomeRetrofitInstance.fetchFromNetwork() //updating some resource from network
}

class YourViewModel{
  val repository = YourRepository()

 //this will start observe the repository livedata and map it to string resource
  var StringResource: Livedata<String> = Transformations.map( repository.IntegerResource ) { integerValue ->
    integerValue.toString()
}
```

My Point is you have to keep alive the LiveData you are transforming. Hope helped.